# Will CT (Certificate Transparency) override the use of CAA and/or DANE/TLSA records?

Tags: public-key, certificates

I'd want to know if some of these competing technologies has more chance to survive. It seems they are thought to solve a similar problem by different manners and I'd want to stick to the most compatible/used/foreesable to win.
It seems it's CT but I'm not sure.
Thanks!

Comment: no, they are complementary CT is at the cert level, CAA is at the hosting level... I also assume this is off topic here and should be moved

Comment: also CAA is useful if you are NOT using https, it can prevent a CA for issuing a fake cert for your domain to an attacker